# MySQL - Using COALESCE with DATE_ADD and DATE_SUB to get next/previous record

Tags: mysql, sql, coalesce

I am trying to query MySQL to select the previous and next record. I need help in using COALESCE and DATE_ADD/DATE_SUB together.

```
SELECT * from `Historical` where `DeltaH` = 'ALTF' and `Date`= 
COALESCE(DATE_SUB('2019-01-21', INTERVAL 1 DAY),
DATE_SUB('2019-01-21',INTERVAL 2 DAY),
DATE_SUB('2019-01-21', INTERVAL 3 DAY));
```

I cannot use the primary key because rows in the table are/will be deleted. The date column also does not necessarily have fixed dates, what I want to find is the next earlier/later date.

```
SELECT * from `Historical` where `DeltaH` = 'ALTF' and `Date`=  
DATE_SUB('2019-01-21', INTERVAL 3 DAY);
```

The above query seems to work, however I need to query for INTERVAL 1 DAY, in case the date does not exist move to INTERVAL 2 DAY....

```
 select * from `Historical` where `DeltaH` = 'ALTF' and `Date`= 
 DATE_SUB('2019-01-21', INTERVAL COALESCE(1,2,3,4,5) DAY);
```

This one does not work either. I understand that the COALESCE() function returns the first non-null value, however I am not able to get it to work using the above query. I have confirmed that data exists for 2019-01-18 but is not being selected. Can you please advise?

I am OK with using an alternate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery to find the most recent date in the table that is less than `2019-01-21` e.g.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `Historical`
WHERE `DeltaH` = 'ALTF' AND `Date`= (SELECT MAX(`Date`)
                                     FROM `Historical`
                                     WHERE `DeltaH` = 'ALTF' AND `Date` < '2019-01-21')
```

To find the closest date that is later, we just adapt the query slightly, using `MIN` and `>`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `Historical`
WHERE `DeltaH` = 'ALTF' AND `Date`= (SELECT MIN(`Date`)
                                     FROM `Historical`
                                     WHERE `DeltaH` = 'ALTF' AND `Date` > '2019-01-21')
```

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I'd write this differently...

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM Historical
  JOIN
     ( SELECT deltah
            , MAX(date) date
         FROM Historical
        WHERE date < '2019-01-21'
        GROUP 
           BY deltah
     ) y
    ON y.deltah = x.deltah
   AND y.date = x.date
 WHERE x.deltah = 'ALTF';
```

Comment: Strawberry, do you think this would be faster than what Nick suggested?

Comment: @quark I think it would be easy to find out

Comment: Thank you. I am just starting and my (test) table is just a few hundred rows, so I can't really tell at this time, however I expect the table to eventually grow to 1-2 million records.

Comment: It's very easy to build a large test table.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like the simplest method:

```
select h.*
from historical h
where h.DeltaH = 'ALTF' and
      h2.Date < '2019-01-21'
order by h.Date DESC
limit 1
```

For best performance, you want an index on `(DeltaH, Date)`.

If you want both the date before and after:

```
(select h.*
 from historical h
 where h.DeltaH = 'ALTF' and
       h2.Date < '2019-01-21'
 order by h.Date desc
 limit 1
) union all
(select h.*
 from historical h
 where h.DeltaH = 'ALTF' and
       h2.Date > '2019-01-21'
 order by h.Date asc
 limit 1
);
```

I'm not sure if one or both comparisons should be have `=`, so you can get results on that date.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I am using the select query to update another table, tried using your and Nick's query, both of them have roughly the same performance (~180 seconds). I have indexes on DeltaH, Date. Just curious, is there an alternate/optimal way to do this faster?

Comment: @Quark . . . This answer explicitly states a composite index on `(DeltaH, Date)`, not multiple indexes.

Comment: Apologies, I should have mentioned that I have a composite index on (DeltaH, Date).